# Does there exist a short range wireless router, or are all 2dBi?

Tags: router, hardware, wifi

When I look at specs for wireless routers, then I either can't find the signal strength or it is 2dBi per antenna.

I am looking for a short range (low antenna dBi) and low throughput (transmitted power dBm) wireless router, but can't find any.

The reason I can't find any, is that because all are 2dBi per antenna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get 1dbi antennas (google search for "1dBi wifi antenna").  You could also look into getting a router which supports dd-wrt and turning down the power or just getting a router that supports this in the first place.  I believe the ubiquiti networks routers support controlling the transmit power.  A drop from 50mW to 5mW would give you 10dB reduction.

Specifying the reason you are needing this may allow for better suggestions.

Comment: Very interesting. It might sounds stupid, but I am concerned about the radiation, when I have to sit in it for 8 hours a day, 5 days a week. So I would prefer one with as low specs as possible.

Comment: I can't buy a ubiquiti router where I live, but if I buy any dd-wrt supported router, I can lower the transmitted power?

Comment: @Sandra: Regarding the radiation concern, [have a look at this](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/are-wifi-waves-harmful).